# Can't get MSBuild to generate debug info when building using the release configuration

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, qmake

I have an automated build process for building Qt applications on Windows. In order to get XP compatible builds, it uses a combination of qmake to generate a Visual Studio project and then MSBuild to build it, as per Qt's docs. So first I use qmake to create the VS project:

```
qmake -spec win32-msvc2013 -tp vc qt_project.pro
```

...and I then use msbuild to build it. (NB: I have Visual Studio 2013 community installed.) I'm using msbuild so that the resulting executable will be compatible with Windows XP. I also need it to generate a pdb file and include debugging symbols, so the specific command I'm using is this:

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=pdbonly /p:DebugSymbols=true /p:PlatformToolset=v120_xp /m:3
```

It builds successfully, and it does indeed build an XP compatible executable, but it does ***not*** generate debug information unless I set the configuration to Debug. But I need it to build using the Release configuration. Basically, it's just ignoring "/p:DebugType=pdbonly /p:DebugSymbols=true" for no reason.

I've just spend quite a bit of time pulling out my hair trying to solve this, but so far the only way I can get what I want is to manually open the Visual Studio project and change the settings for the release configuration. This is not acceptable -- I need to automate this!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why to use MsBuild here. MsBuild is for command-line build using Visual Studio solution or project file? Those types of project files IMHO are just a convenience when we do Qt debug/programming using Visual Studio. And for Qt app project build purposes is much easier/better to skip all the intermediate steps and start the build the executable directly from Qt own .pro project file with qmake and then jom (Qt own make/nmake replacement, very good in parallelizing the build):

```
set config=release
rem set config=debug

rem provide any qmake options you need
qmake myProject.pro -r "CONFIG+=%config%" -o MyMakefile
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
   echo qmake failed.
   goto :failure
)

rem make step now needs jom or nmake only
jom /f MyMakefile

if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
   echo Failed to compile!
   goto :failure
)
rem running installer maker, etc.
:faliure
```

Make sure to provide the system path to an appropriate Qt bin directory.

P.S. Speaking of XP compatibility. It seems to be the demand for the build itself (because of tools like qmake and jom and compiler cl.exe), and the product of the build running on Windows XP does not depend on where it is build.

Comment: I should have clarified this in my original question, and I'll make an edit, but the makefile generated by qmake will not create an XP compatible build. Qt's docs say that to do that you have to create a Visual Studio project and set the platform toolkit to v120_xp, hence the need to use MSBuild.

Comment: I am unsure of that. We have a big project under Windows and always build with qmake/jom. In fact you are talking to one who created all that build. Visual Studio is a convenience and qmake .pro file is what this whole build starts from.

Comment: If this is true then I'll happily ditch the Visual Studio step, but as is qmake / jom will produce builds that don't work with XP. Is there a setting I have to use to make XP compatible builds?

Comment: XP compatible? I guess that means being able running the build on XP. And that's it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow

Comment: The Windows version that you run the build process on should be higher than XP.